# Sort a json data based on a some json value in angular2

Tags: javascript, json

This is my json:

```
{
   {
    "FirstName": "Adam" ,
    "Order": 3
   },
   {
    "FirstName": "Baron" ,
    "Order": 1
   },
   {
    "FirstName": "Ashton" ,
    "Order": 4
   },
   {
    "FirstName": "Kara" ,
    "Order": 2
   }
}
```

I want to order this based on "Order" value. 
My hunt did not get me anything efficient.

Answer (score 2):

You can use pipe, **[`Sorting`](http://angular.io/guide/pipes)**

```
*ngFor="let option of options | orderBy:'Order'"
```

Comment: I voted down, because in the same documentation link you provided it is clearly stated that you should not use pipes for sorting: "This isn't an oversight. Angular doesn't offer such pipes because they perform poorly and prevent aggressive minification. Both filter and orderBy require parameters that reference object properties."

Answer (score 2):

```
var people = [
   {
    "FirstName": "Adam" ,
    "Order": 3
   },
   {
    "FirstName": "Baron" ,
    "Order": 1
   },
   {
    "FirstName": "Ashton" ,
    "Order": 4
   },
   {
    "FirstName": "Kara" ,
    "Order": 2
   }
];
function sortJSON(data, key) {
    return data.sort(function (a, b) {
        var x = a[key];
        var y = b[key];
        return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
    });
}

var people2 = sortJSON(people, 'Order');
console.log("JSON",JSON.stringify(people2));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this with [Lodash](https://lodash.com/):

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';

_.sortBy(people, p => p.Order);
```

The advantage is that is also comes with a lot more functionality that can be very handy. Just be mindful of what you import from it, so not to bloat your output bundle.

Don't use pipes for sorting. Snippet from the [Pipes documentation](https://angular.io/guide/pipes):

> Appendix: No FilterPipe or OrderByPipe
>
> Angular doesn't provide pipes for filtering or sorting lists.
>   Developers familiar with AngularJS know these as filter and orderBy.
>   There are no equivalents in Angular.
>
> This isn't an oversight. Angular doesn't offer such pipes because they
>   perform poorly and prevent aggressive minification. Both filter and
>   orderBy require parameters that reference object properties. Earlier
>   in this page, you learned that such pipes must be impure and that
>   Angular calls impure pipes in almost every change-detection cycle.